# Avoid type ahead searching user's personal contact list in a Lotus Notes' name field

Tags: database, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I like the type ahead feature feature in Lotus Notes but I want it to avoid suggesting any name that is not in the "PUBLIC" database. We're having problems where users are getting the "Ambiguous Name" dialog and selecting the wrong name in a custom Notes application we are developing. Is there any way to have the type ahead feature only search for names in the "PUBLIC" database for the custom application but keep the default search scope the same everywhere else?

Comment: this question belongs on ServerFault since it is related to Notes administration.  I'm voting to move it there.

Comment: Is it a server issue? We only want the lookup to happen in a specific custom notes application, not everywhere.

Comment: Ok, that's fine.  Just reword your question to make it clear this is for a custom application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to turn that feature off for a particular application, but if you want to display a drop-down list of users to choose from, the @NameLookup formula can help:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_NAMELOOKUP_7699.html

Comment: You should probably find a link to the doc on IBM's site, rather than some random site that has left their server wide open.